# iOS app review process: app requires external hardware (connecting over WiFi)

Tags: ios, external, hardware, appstore-approval

We've written an app for our clients that connects to external hardware over Wifi (hardware designed by our client). My question is, how do we go about submitting this for review? The software won't do very much without the hardware. Just to be clear, the hardware does not connect directly to the iPad with a cable, it connects over WiFi only.

I just want to get some clarity on what we need to do to get this app through the review process and into the App Store.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of [StageMix for M7CL, LS9 and CL](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/ls9-stagemix/id406087165?mt=8) and it has exactly this issue - the hardware it works with is a somewhat expensive dongle ;)

We added disconnected demo mode where all of the application's UI works - only difference is that nothing is remote controlled. This has the added benefit of allowing customers to try the app out when the hardware isn't handy.

Apple has always been happy reviewing the demo mode and presumably never tested it connected.

I do suggest that the iTunes Store metadata for the App - and if possible the user interface - is very clear about the external hardware requirements

Comment: Thanks Marko. This is very helpful. We were thinking of perhaps shipping a "simulator" app that runs on another device or Mac, but perhaps the right approach is to build in a "test mode"...

Comment: Hi, I do not understand if simply providing a "demo mode" has been helpfull to you for passing the review process. Please let me know, I'm in the same situation: I sell a wifi device and the application connect to it via wifi.

Comment: There are no concrete guarantees from the process. However, anything that lets the reviewer looks at your app is likely to be a bonus.

Answer (score 4):

One of my recent updates to DAQ-app failed approval with a note that I needed to show a video of it working with the hardware.
My demo mode let them test some functionality, and the video showed the connectivity. I just hosted the video as a private video on YouTube, and it was accepted quickly after I submitted the video.
The next update was accepted with the same video and a note that there were only minor changes, and no changes to the connectivity.

Answer (score 3):

I emailed Apple this week to ask what their current policy on this is, and they said we have to ship the hardware to them. They also said they can return it if needed, but that we'd have to ship the hardware to them again for every future app update too.

Comment: Did you try publishing you're app to the Apple Store anyways without sending the hardware? In case, the accept it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I had same experience. our App is 
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jia-jia-yi/id497092682?mt=8.
This app also works with a device. 
But we was lucky,  apple did not ask us to support the hardware to them.
Hope you are lucky too.
 :)

Comment: Thanks! Our app won't do much without the hardware so will be difficult for Apple to verify or properly test.

Answer (score 1):

Apple required me to send in hardware

Comment: can you please share what was procedure to ship hardware?

Comment: Apple provided me an address to ship to after the app was in review. It was provided via the Resolution Center.

Comment: I have the same situation, does hardware should be FCC compliant ?

Answer (score 1):

We recently submitted an app that required our hardware to be submitted too. The address it was asked to be shipped to is:

Apple, Inc.
1 Infinite Loop, M/S: 124-2APP
Cupertino, CA 95014
USA

It's probably best that you submit the app first and let it get stuck on that process so when you send it in, you can direct it to the proper person in charge. As for FCC, you need to fill out this form if shipping from outside US:

http://transition.fcc.gov/Forms/Form740/740.pdf

Other notes provided by Apple:

- A separate FCC Form 740 must be used for each different radio-frequency device or component in the shipment; however, a form is not required for subassemblies, parts, or components of radio-frequency devices.
- The form may be completed by the shipper or recipient, but if the form is not sent with the original shipping documents by the shipper, the shipment may be delayed in customs.
- Ensure all serial and ID numbers are available as well as the name and address of the original manufacturer.

I hope that helps!