# If I make an iPhone or iPad app for my custom hardware product do I need to send a sample product to Apple?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, hardware, mfi

Communication is based on Low Energy Bluetooth and I do use a custom profile.

Do I need to join the MFi program?
Is there a link to a form I fill out to let Apple know I want to send them some hardware for app evaluation?

If I do need to send a sample how long is the process for approval?
Do you only have to do it one time or do they want to test the hardware for every app update I make?

Would love to get info from someone who's had experience with this process.
Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: SO might be the wrong site for this question.  Maybe ask Apple?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193073/ios-app-review-process-app-requires-external-hardware-connecting-over-wifi