# Submitting iOS app that requires external hardware

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I want to submit an app to the store that requires external hard ware. You cannot do much in the app without the hardware, so I was wondering what is the best way forward with submitting app to the store. I have read some reports that say Apple require us to ship them the hardware. Have also read reports where people say a video the app has sufficed.

I was reading some answers in this thread here

[iOS app review process: app requires external hardware (connecting over WiFi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193073/ios-app-review-process-app-requires-external-hardware-connecting-over-wifi)

I was going to create a video of the app and the hardware working. In iTunes connect, under App Review Information, can add an attachment, so was going to put it under there.

Do you think this would be enough for Apple? Or do you think we will have to actually send them the hardware?

Looking for advice from people who have experience in submitting apps that require external hardware and what your experience was. Did the review process take much longer? If so, how long?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did this end up? Could you submit your app and have it reviewed only thank to the video, or did you have to ship a real device?

Comment: Just filmed the app and the hardware side by side showing how app interacts with hardware. Then added that video to the meta data when uploading the app to app store. Had no issues at all, was reviewed and accepted within few days

Answer (score 2):

I can't respond about the hardware aspect of things however I did create an App that was only allowed to be used within a specific country. Apple requested a video, provided and approved. Occasionally they would ask for another one for updates but not always.

Doing a screen capture isn't enough, has to be a video of you using the App. The review process took a bit longer than usual, longest wait period was the queue of about a week, once that was done each back and forth took an additional day, so at the end of it took about another 3 days for approval. I put it as a private video on youtube and submitted a link, then I could also track when they watched it.